# Default editor in Eclipse team synchronize view

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor, eclipse-cdt

Does anyone know how to change the default editor for text compare in Eclipse Team synchronize view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want the default editor to not be the compare editor, or do you want a different type of comparison (like binary) in the compare editor?

Comment: I have added syntax highlighting for a non-standard language to eclipse using Wordfile Editor plugin (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wfe-wordfile-editor) and it works fine on its own. But whenever I compare files of this type, it uses the default editor which has no syntax highlighting.

Comment: You mean the default editor within the compare editor? As far as I know you can't get the syntax highlighting in the compare editor. You would have to use the compare framework to do some kind of custom editor.